# How do I make buttons with titles above to be side-by-side and aligned in the center? (I just started learning couple of days ago)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here's I got so far: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAkhB.png)

Here's my HTML:

```
 <h2 class="section-title">BUTTONS</h2>
        <div class="buttons">
         
            <div class="button-default">
                <small class="btn-label">Default</small>
                <button>Primary Button</button>
                <button>Secondary Button</button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="button-hovered">
                <small class="btn-label">Hovered</small>
                <button>Primary Button</button>
                <button>Secondary Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want it to look like this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTD0u.png)

Comment: Can you add the css you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following css:

```
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 20px;
}

.button-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 20px;
}
```

Also, update your HTML to be like this.

```
<div class="button-container button-default">
   <small class="btn-label">Default</small>
   <button>Primary Button</button>
   <button>Secondary Button</button>
</div>
            
<div class="button-container button-hovered">
   <small class="btn-label">Hovered</small>
   <button>Primary Button</button>
   <button>Secondary Button</button>
</div>
```

This will achieve the side-by-side positioning